# How initialize multi dimensional vectors of an unknown size, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

in my project I would need create variable multidimensional matrix by std:vector with variable size. I found correctly code below, which can create this:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct md_vector
{
    using type = std::vector<typename md_vector<T, N - 1>::type>;
};

 template<typename T>
 struct md_vector<T, 1>
 {
    using type = std::vector<T>;
 };

 Template<typename T, std::size_t N>
 using md_vector_t = typename md_vector<T, N>::type;


//using
//this create 3 dimensional vectors of int - std:vector<std:vector<std:vector<int>>>
 md_vector_t<int, 3> matrix;
```

But now i dont know ho use this matrix? I would like initialize whole matrix to 0....by example 4 dimensional matrix, each vector 7 integers.... 7 x 7 x 7 x 7 integers ? And after initialize how i can assign value? matrix[0][0][0][0] - this i cannot, because I dont know dimension size.

Thank you very much for some advice...

Comment: Just to make sure I'm reading this right, you don't know whether you will  have say vector of vector or perhaps vector of vector of vector of vector of vector of vector until runtime?

Comment: however, that's not really possible, is it?  All types must be known at compile time.

Comment: You can't use vectors unless you know the dimensions at compile time.

Comment: xaxxon, you can see in code above, that is possible make vectors with variable dimension....

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deal with this insane situation is to use `resize()`. Let the compiler figure out how to initialize the vector:

```
md_vector_t<int, 4> matrix;

matrix.resize(7);
```

This is going to resize the first dimension. Now, you need to resize each individual element in the first dimension, in order to construct the second dimension.

```
for (auto &a:matrix)
    a.resize(7);
```

Before soon, you figure out how to let range iteration work for you. Something like this:

```
md_vector_t<int, 4> matrix;

matrix.resize(7);

for (auto &a:matrix)
{
    a.resize(7);
    for (auto &b:a)
    {
        b.resize(7);
        for (auto &c:b)
        {
             c.resize(7);
        }
    }
}
```

Counting this off on my fingers, I'm pretty fairly certain this'll initialize all four dimensions here.

Before C++11, this would've been agony.

Now, I'm not sure exactly why you say "matrix[0][0][0][0] - this i cannot, by i dont know dimension size". Because that's exactly how you would go around peeking and poking at this sucker.

Each element in the matrix will be value-constructed to 0. If you want to initialize the values to something else, just use the same nested range iteration approach to initialize the values.

Now, as far as a template for initializing a matrix of arbitrary dimensions, it should be trivial to take this same approach and use the same approach as your existing template: a specialization for a 1-dimensional vector, and a the default template that invokes `resize()`, then performs range iteration to recursively invoke itself on the values in its container.